# How does 'While' loop and 'for' loop build in programming languages?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

suddenly a question goes over my mind which is how the `WHILE` loop and `FOR` loop has been built into programming languages
and can we make something like it and write it the same way we write the loops?

I tried to make this code in dart language but it doesn't work and doesn't seem to be like the normal `FOR` loop

```
dynamic forLoop(condition, body){
  if(condition){
    body();
    forLoop(condition, body);
  }
}

void main(){
  forLoop( (Something.i<5), (){print(Something.i); Something.i++;} );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar question for Python [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387889/how-does-the-python-for-loop-actually-work).

I tried the same approach using dis module for while loop.

```
def f():
    n = 0
    while n < 2:
        print("body")
        n += 1
    return None

dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (n)
  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       18 (to 36)
  4     >>   12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 ('body')
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 POP_TOP
  5          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 (1)
             24 INPLACE_ADD
             26 STORE_FAST               0 (n)
  3          28 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             30 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             32 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         6 (to 12)
  6     >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can find details about [Python Bytecode Instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) in the dis module.